# to help with -ing

Tags: phrase-usage

From https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/airlines-cancel-change-flights-to-us-over-5g-dispute-/6403568.html:

> An altimeter sends radio waves from an airplane to the ground to measure how far above the ground an airplane is traveling. Pilots use it **to help with landing planes**, especially during bad weather.

I'm not sure who/what helps who/what in the bolded part.

I think if it expresses the pilots' purpose of using an altimeter, the doer of "to help with" should be the same as the subject of the main clause (pilots).

> The infinitive of purpose can only be used if the doer of the action expressed by the infinitive is the same as the subject of the main clause.
> https://www.grammaring.com/the-infinitive-of-purpose

Can I paraphrase it as *"so that the pilots can help planes with landing"*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a reasonable and logical paraphrase, but you can't necessarily count on that grammatical construction to match those people.

> Road crews spread salt on the roads *to help with driving* in icy weather.

In this case the road crews are not the ones doing the driving.

A better expansion of the phrase in your example would just be "Pilots use it *to help with **the landing of** planes*." It still leaves the question of who is doing the landing unaddressed. In this case the context makes it clear; in other cases it might not.

Comment: Is the salt helping? And, is the altimeter helping in the original sentence?

Comment: @K.N. Hm, that's tricky to think about. The simple answer is of course they are. But if we're getting particular about grammar: Does salt help the driving? Or do road crews "help with driving" by *using* salt? In the construction "X uses Y to Z," do we understand X or Y as the thing that does Z? I'm not sure I could say in a way that works for every situation. Sometimes it becomes a problem in logic or philosophy rather than language ("The painter used a brush to paint the wall"—what painted the wall, the brush or the painter?).

Comment: Thank you. It may be irrelevant to think about who helps and who is helped. I'm feeling that "facilitate" can be a good alternative to "help with".

Answer (score 0):

Not really, in the original example the verb ***to land*** is used transitively, while in your attempt to paraphrase it is used intransitively. You can look at the original example in this way:

> Pilots use altimeter to help *(them, the pilots)* with landing planes *(The altimeter helps the pilots, but it is the pilots that land the planes)*.

The structure is

> X helps Y ***with doing*** something *(where Y is the agent of the action of doing)*.

Comment: So, is it correct to paraphrase it as "so that the pilots can help themselves with landing planes"?

Comment: Not "themselves" but "them". It is the altimeter that is doing the helping, so a reflexive pronoun is not needed here. _... so that it (the altimeter) may help the pilots with landing the planes._

Comment: I thought the doer of "to help" should be the same as the subject of the main clause (pilots), shouldn't it? https://www.grammaring.com/the-infinitive-of-purpose

Comment: _[I called him to help me](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+called+him+to+help+me%22+&sxsrf=AOaemvIx3kfOvzcRq9GsaJhRAadW9Tk0dA%3A1642700069776&source=hp&ei=JZ3pYaPXLLSRhbIP8qaW8A4&iflsig=ALs-wAMAAAAAYemrNWhS2nHFwmvD-21SNxBcVGLu8t7G&ved=0ahUKEwjj_YPR7sD1AhW0SEEAHXKTBe4Q4dUDCAo&uact=5&oq=%22I+called+him+to+help+me%22+&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BAgjECc6CwgAEIAEELEDEIMBOg4ILhCABBCxAxDHARCjAjoICAAQgAQQsQM6BQguEIAEOgUIABCABDoLCC4QgAQQxwEQ0QM6CAguEIAEELEDOgoIABCABBCxAxAKOgsILhCABBCxAxCDAToGCAAQFhAeOggIIRAWEB0QHjoFCCEQoAE6BwghEAoQoAFQAFiFgwFgrokBaANwAHgAgAFfiAGcEZIBAjMxmAEAoAEB&sclient=gws-wiz)_.